# Appending property to ArrayBuffer sent over DataChannel

Tags: javascript, webrtc, arraybuffer

I am currently receiving chunks from a stream of a video that I send over the DataChannel to a peer who will then reconstruct the video on the other end.

I have this part working just fine but I would like to add which chunk # it was that was received so that it doesn't matter if they happen to arrive in a different order than intended.

Initially I thought that adding a parameter `chunkId` would work but when I do `.data.chunkId` on the receiver side, it is undefined.

Then I tried to stringify the ArrayBuffer along with the `chunkId` using `JSON.stringify({ "chunkId": chunkId, "data": chunk })` but it causes problems when I parse it on the other end (`Unexpected end of JSON input` and `Unexpected token , in JSON at position #`)

DataChannels also accept blobs so I thought I would try that but the sender is using node.js which apparently can't do that. I wasn't quite able to figure out how to get around that.

The last thing I tried was to simply append the `chunkId` to the beginning/end of the ArrayBuffer itself but when I try to create a new array I get the error `source is too large` when trying to add the chunk itself.

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to intermingle sending text and ArrayBuffers, and check for them on reception:

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(e => log(e));

var dc1 = pc1.createDataChannel("chat", {negotiated: true, id: 0});
var dc2 = pc2.createDataChannel("chat", {negotiated: true, id: 0});

dc2.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
dc2.onmessage = e => {
  if (e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    log("Got ArrayBuffer!");
  } else if (e.data instanceof Blob) {
    log("Got Blob!");
  } else {
    log("> " + e.data);
  }
}

button.onclick = e => dc1.send(new ArrayBuffer(8));
chat.onkeypress = e => {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
  dc1.send(chat.value);
  chat.value = "";
};

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
Chat: <input id="chat"><button id="button">Send ArrayBuffer</button><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

So why not send the chunk id ahead of each ArrayBuffer?

Comment: I figured sending it in two parts would be more prone to errors but I can work out some workarounds to get around/alleviate them. It's unfortunate it cannot be done at the same time