# Transmitting an ArrayBuffer with metadata (over a webRTC data connection)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, arraybuffer

In docs, I see the following example for sending a string over a WebRTC data channel:

```
var message = messageInputBox.value;
sendChannel.send(message);
```

I'm trying to send images and video - so I create an `ArrayBuffer`:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
     // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
     data.media = reader.result; // ArrayBuffer
     outboundMediaQueue.push(data);
});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data.media);
```

I can transmit this ArrayBuffer, but I'm trying to also send some metadata alongside it (media ID).  Given that I can't `JSON.serialize` an ArrayBuffer - how can I transfer this data with corresponding metadata?

**Update:**

This works:

```
sendChannel.send(data.media); // sending `ArrayBuffer` only
```

But this doesn't work:

```
sendChannel.send(data); // arbitrary object with desired metadata
```

And this also doesn't work:

```
sendChannel.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Update 2**

I've composed the following module that seems to handle the encoding and decoding.  It's not quite fully tested and hasn't been run against large files; I'll keep this updated as I figure out what works:

```
define([], function () {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_2_–_rewrite_the_DOMs_atob()_and_btoa()_using_JavaScript's_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8
    // https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

    const arrayBufferConverter = {};
    arrayBufferConverter.bufferToString = function (outboundBuffer) {
        const dataView = new DataView(outboundBuffer);
        const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8'); // base64?
        const decodedString = decoder.decode(dataView);
        return decodedString;
    }

    arrayBufferConverter.stringToBuffer = function (inboundString) {
        var encoded = new TextEncoderLite('utf-8').encode(inboundString);
        var b64Encoded = base64js.fromByteArray(encoded);
        return b64Encoded;
    }

    return arrayBufferConverter;
});
```

**Update 3**

Since my only real need here is to pair metadata with the `ArrayBuffer`, I'm going to forget the encoding/decoding nonsense and just generate a digest on both ends of the transaction:

```
arrayBufferConverter.getDigestFromBuffer = function (buffer) {
    const view = new DataView(buffer);
    const numBytes = view.byteLength;
    const interval = Math.floor(numBytes / 32);
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var digest = "";
    while (currentIndex < numBytes) {
        digest += view.getInt8(currentIndex);
        currentIndex += interval;
    }
    return digest;
}
```

This way I'll send the `ArrayBuffers` and corresponding metadata in two separate requests and manage the pairing with some basic queue logic.  This totally eliminates ongoing processing cost and the risks inherent in encoding/decoding large media files in favor of a small fixed cost of pairing logic.  I'll leave this open in case anyone has any other recommendations.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant like image metadata before. You can add more attributes to the `data` object, can't you? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - just updated with some examples of what I'm going for

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I'll look into this later. I hate to say it but you'll either need a 3rd party library, or you'll need to learn the image/jpeg binary format (at least how the header bytes are organized, not necessarily the compression format).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - yikes.  I'll also start digging in that direction.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending property to ArrayBuffer sent over DataChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629478/appending-property-to-arraybuffer-sent-over-datachannel)

Comment: @jib I think it's worth leaving this up given how fast WebRTC is moving.  There may be another solution now that the other question will never have a chance to attract as an answer.

Comment: @SB2055 What do you mean by "*the other question will never have a chance to attract as an answer*"? If there's a new answer to the question, anyone can post one. If you want to shift attention, offer a bounty.

Comment: @Bergi To attract an updated answer, someone would have to seek that question out and post an answer despite one being selected.  Readers would then have to take the extra step to scroll past the selected (potentially outdated) answer.  I didn't see that question before but I don't see how leaving this up would do anything but help, again, given how fast this particular tech is moving.

Comment: @SB2055 I found a library and [submitted an issue requesting for support of TypedArrays](https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs/issues/27). Regardless of whether they do or not, you can still use it, just do your manipulation in base64 encoded strings or binary strings, and then use the file reader API to convert to TypedArrays for transmission. Unfortunately until the library supports TypedArrays, your application's memory consumption will be pretty massive though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see - thank you for that.  What are your thoughts on just sending the TypedArray independent of the metadata per Update 3?  I am targeting mobile clients as well so I have to be mindful of memory consumption - though I haven't yet profiled update 3 vs piexifjs.